# htc one n8 monitor mode

Tags: android, linux, wifi

Я установил на телефон kali nethunter, не получает запустить  (monitor mode) через airmon,iw,iwconfig. На фото вот такие ошибки мне выдают. Всё перепробывал, кто знает как мне сделать. В инете пишет что нужно что то делать с ядром.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может в интернете говорят правду? П. С. Насколько я знаю, надо использвать не `sudo`, а `su`

Comment: зачем sudo или su, если уже и так суперпользователь

Comment: Дело не в su, это всё есть. Мне нужно знать как решить проблему с драйверами и то что незапускается режим monitor